# Difference between RealmResults vs RealmList?

Tags: android, realm

I would like to know what is the difference between `RealmResults` and `RealmList`.

The only difference I see is that realmlist is to input data, while RealmResults is to run a query.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please see the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html) and [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html). Especially this part:

> RealmList is used to model one-to-many relationships in a RealmObject.

RealmResults are always the result of a database query. RealmList can be used inside of a RealmObject to define One-To-Many relationships (RealmResults can't).

Also this part:

> RealmList has two modes: A managed and non-managed mode. In managed mode all objects are persisted inside a Realm, in non-managed mode it works as a normal ArrayList.

A RealmList can be non-managed, thus act like a normal ArrayList, whereas RealmResults is a "window" into the database. Objects are not copied and put into the RealmResults, they are only referenced.

In short RealmResults are always a product of a database query, whereas RealmLists don't have to be.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not a bad question for someone who is starting (I mean by negative score)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I think it is the sort of thing that is clearly described in the Realm documentation, so I kind of understand that people would think asking such a question is a bit lazy and downvote it.

Comment: nothing lazy, I understand but before you put anything look, but if you can not find it (even if you are) will have to leave doubts and ask.
This is my case, I do not tell you to be other than as saying.

Yet I have found with your links where to look next time. Thanks